# Angular7 Integration tests of component "Failed: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError:"

Tags: angular, integration-testing, angular7, angular-test

I keep getting this error and have been through the docs and various threads and can't figure out why these errors are happening as they don't make any sense.

My spec configuration with 1 single simple test:

```js
describe('AddVideoComponent', () => {
  let component: AddVideoComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<AddVideoComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        MatSnackBarModule,
        FormsModule
      ],
      declarations: [AddVideoComponent, CleanLinkPipe],
      providers: [RestService, NgRedux, AdalService],
      schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
    })
      .compileComponents()
      .then(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AddVideoComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        fixture.detectChanges();
      });
  }));

  it('should create form group with 5 controls', () => {
    component.ngOnInit();
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(component.addVideoForm.contains('title')).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Errors I'm getting:

```
Failed: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined
```

+

```
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'ngOnInit' of undefined
```

Now in my component, I'm not subscribing to anything in any way, there's no subscriptions of any kind.

Comment: Provide your component code at least, and at best a [mcve] of the issue.

Comment: My best guess without any further code is that there is an error occurring while trying to create your component (the first error), thus the component is never being initialized and causing the second error. Can you provide the code for your `AddVideoComponent`?

Comment: @DanielWStrimpel -- ah, you are right. I found out that my integration test was a bit too much and instead should've just use a test-class for the rest service, not the whole rest service itself. Seems like such an obvious mistake now, sorry! Happy to mark your answer as right if you post it as an answer.